# How to check if ListBox contains same text as another ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have 2 Listbox and I want to check the first Listbox text so that I can add them to the second Listbox. Like, let's say that I have a car registration plate on the first Listbox **( 02-TH-93 )** and now I want to add on my second Listbox that same plate **( 02-TH-93 )** *BUT* if that plate doesn't exist on the first ListBox then it should just show a message error.

*For example:*

ListBox1:
02-TH-93
|
06-JK-58
|
07-HJ-95
|
02-FG-56

ListBox2:
**02-TH-93**
|
**06-JK-58**
|
**07-HJ-95**
|
*45-ER-01* (Show message error now because there's no match of this registration plate on listbox1)

I tried this but it doesn't really make a lot of sense I guess:

```cs
            parking.Entrance = textBoxEntrance.Text;
            parking.Exit = textBoxExit.Text;
            if(parking.Entrance == parking.Exit) 
            { 
                  listBoxExit.Items.Add("Plate: " + parking.Exit + " Exited ");
            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I have now understood correctly, this should work after your wishes. If you do not understand something, just ask again!

[image: picture from the UI]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace plateManager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_LB1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtbox1.Text))
                lb1.Items.Add(txtbox1.Text);
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter something!");
            txtbox1.Text = "";
        }

        private void button_LB2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Asks if the textbox is empty or has space
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtbox2.Text))
            {
                List<string> allPlates = new List<string>();

                /*The list box will be read from top to bottom 
                  and will add each entry in this list box to the list called "allPlates".*/
                for (int i = 0; i < lb1.Items.Count; i++)
                    allPlates.Add(lb1.Items[i].ToString());

                if (ExistsCheck(txtbox2.Text, allPlates))
                    lb2.Items.Add(txtbox2.Text);
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("This license plate was not found!");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter something!");
            //Reset the textbox
            txtbox2.Text = "";
        }

        private bool ExistsCheck(string newPlate, List<string> allPlates)
        {
            //Each entry will be checked if it matches, if it does, the boolean is set to true and will be returned afterwards.
            bool result = false;
            foreach (var plate in allPlates)
                if (plate.Equals(newPlate))
                    result = true;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `Listbox.ItemsSource` is a list of strings so you could just loop through one of those lists and look for a match like this:

```
private bool IsInFirst(string plateToAdd, List<string> plates)
    {
        foreach(string plate in plates)
        {
            if (plate.Equals(plateToAdd))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

If it returns `true` the list contains the plate to add and if it returns `false` it doesn't. [This](https://wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/listbox-control/) tutorial helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a variate as I understand it, so it asks if the "plate" is present in lb1. If yes then add it if not ignore it and make a message box

```
private bool ExistsCheck(string newPlate, List<string> allPlates)
    {
        bool result = false;
        foreach (var plate in allPlates)
            if (plate.Equals(newPlate))
                result = true;
        return result;
    }

private void AddAndCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> allPlates = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < lb1.Items.Count; i++)
            allPlates.Add(lb1.Items[i].ToString());

        if (ExistsCheck(tb_plate.Text, allPlates))
        {
            // If its return False
            lb2.Items.Add(tb_plate.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            // If its return True
            MessageBox.Show("It is not present in listbox 1");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a better way, and not as "zSmyley" had shown you, because you should not go from the loop with return and break.

Comment: I have 2 textboxes, 1 for the entrance plate where after I click a button it enters new item on lb1 and other one for the exit plate where after I click other button it enters new item on lb2, so the code its not really working...

Comment: Then I don't understand your problem, you want to check a plate before it can be added? So it is queried in the lb1 whether the is available if yes then it should be added in lb2 and if not then only a message box with the message that it does not work or how do you mean that?

Comment: So, I have a txtbox1 for marking the car entrance, you type the plate and it adds to lb1, and I have a txtbox2 for marking the car exit, you type the plate and if the plate you type on the txtbox2 matches a plate thats on the lb1 it adds it to the lb2 basically saying that plate exited the parking lot. In case the plate you type on txtbox2 dosnt match any plate on lb1 it should show a message error.